# What's the name of the generics syntax in: "X.<String, String>method()"

Tags: java, generics, syntax

Sometimes this (relatively strange looking) syntax is required to avoid a type mismatch. But what's the name of that syntax actually?

Usage example from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (r07):

[ImmutableMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) defines a method

```
public static <K, V> Builder<K, V> builder()
```

It can be used like this:

```
ImmutableMap<String, String> map = 
        ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder().put("a", "A").build();
```

Which is by the way the inlined version of:

```
Builder<String, String> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();       
ImmutableMap<String, String> map = builder.put("a", "A").build();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that syntax has a particular name. I've reviewed the JLS and it just mentions it as "a call to a **generic method**".

In your case one could narrow it down to "a call to a non-static generic method".

If you're referring to the fact that the type parameters are present on the call-side, you simply say "a call to a generic method **with explicit type parameters**".

To give an example where it is (sort of) mentioned in the JLS

> *Deciding whether a method is applicable will, in the case of generic methods (§8.4.4), require that actual type arguments be determined. Actual type arguments may be passed explicitly or implicitly. If they are passed implicitly, they must be inferred (§15.12.2.7) from the types of the argument expressions.*

Comment: `ImmutableMap.builder()` alone is "a call to a generic method", too (and my last example shows, that it still allows to infer the type parameters when doing an assignment). I didn't find a special notion for `ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()` either, but it *should* have a specific name IMO :-)

Comment: Thanks - quite a long name, but at least I don't have to remember it as "type period angle parameter comma parameter angle methodname" anmore ;-)

Answer (score 3):

if the syntax you are talking about is angular brackets, then they are called TYPE PARAMETERS.

Comment: No, that's too general - "type parameters" applies to all kinds of generics syntaxes, e.g. also to `new HashMap<String, String>()` - but I'm looking specifically for the name of the syntax in `X.<String, String>method()`, where the angle brackets (type parameters) directly follow the period.

Comment: But that is what they *are*.  If you want to be more specific, they would be 'generic method type parameters'